# Add a "z" axis to an existing graph and make it 3d

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, mahalanobis

I have a data frame as following:

```
z<-data()

      cost time Period Type
    1    72   51     10    1
    2    68   60     10    1
    3    79   43     10    1
    4    67   79     10    1
    5    79   67     10    1
    6    89   35     10    1
    7    80   34     10    1
    8    78   45     10    1
    9    76   47     10    1
    10   69   57     10    1
    11   67   56     10    1
    12   69   45     10    1
    13   79   57     10    1
    14   70   56     10    1
    15   80   56     10    1
    16   89   56     10    1
    17    3    5      1    0
    18    5    8      2    0
    19   89   67      3    0
    20   46   56      4    0
    21   23   34      5    0
```

I draw mahalanobis distance between the project type 0 and project type 1 as following.

```
  x<-z[,c(1,2)]
require(robustbase)
  x.mcd=covMcd(x)
   title(main="Distance from benchmark space", col.main="red", font.main=4)

  drawMahal(x,center=x.mcd$center,covariance=x.mcd$cov,quantile = c(0.975, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25,0.01) ,m =1000,lwdcrit =2 ,col=ifelse(x1$Type==1,"green","blue"),pch=2,col.axis="blue",frame.plot=TRUE,cex=2)
  legend("top",pch=c(2,2),col=c("green","blue"),c("Current","Benchmark"),bty="o",box.col="darkgreen",cex=.8)
  axis(1, col = "blue",col.axis = "blue",  lwd = 0.5,tck=1,col.ticks="light gray")
  axis(2, col = "blue", col.axis = "blue", lwd = 2,tck=1,col.ticks="light gray")
```

So the out put is like following:
[image: Mahalanobis distance]

> Q1: How can I add an axis of period from dataframe z to the above
>   graph to make the graph 3d shape.
>
> Q2 add lines from blue points to the centroid of mahalanobis space?
>   and add the line from the blue point of period 1 to 5 respectively
>   with the different color.

I have used plot_ly and make it 3d but Still I could not draw ellipses around it.

```
f<-plot_ly(n,x=n$cost,y=n$time,z=n$Period,color = n$Type,type="scatter3d", mode="markers")
```

and the graph that I got it is as following:
[image: 3d navigation]
For the eliplipses I wrote the following codes, but it does not show anything.

```
z <- layout(f, title = 'Highlighting Regions with Circles', 
                                   shapes = list(
                                    list(type = 'circle',
                                 xref = 'x', x0 = min(f$cost), x1 = max(f$cost),
                        yref = 'y', y0 = min(f$time), y1 = max(f$time),zref='z',z0=1,z1=1,
                                    fillcolor = 'blue', line = list(color = 'red'),
                            opacity = 0.1)))
```

Comment: Have a look at the `plotly` packages, https://plot.ly/r/

Comment: Thanks I will look at it.

Comment: I have used the following code and make it 3d but still it is not What I want. 'f<-plot_ly(n,x=n$cost,y=n$time,z=n$Period,color = n$Type,type="scatter3d", mode="markers")'

Comment: To have a surface, you may need something like `plot_ly(z = volcano, type = "surface")`, please check the structure of `volcano` dataset, which may not be the same as yours.

Comment: But when I use Volcano It does not show anything. Actually, I do not understand Volcano graph. If we can draw ellipses around yellow points and show the center point of type one or yellow points. and then draw lines between purple lines. It would be great

Comment: for the ellipses I just wrote these codes:'z <- layout(f, title = 'Highlighting Regions with Circles', 
                                   shapes = list(
                                    list(type = 'circle',
                                 xref = 'x', x0 = min(f$cost), x1 = max(f$cost),
                        yref = 'y', y0 = min(f$time), y1 = max(f$time),zref='z',z0=1,z1=1,
                                    fillcolor = 'blue', line = list(color = 'red'),
                            opacity = 0.1)))'